# How to upload code to Google Domains

Tags: angularjs, dns, server

I have recently bought a domain name in google Domains. How would I upload the code written in angular to the domain.

I dnt know how to proceed. I am new to this so please guid me.

Do I need to buy again something to use this domain. How should use the google domain so that my code works.

Answer (score 1):

You only bought the domain, you did not buy a web host as well.

If you log into your account you can click "Configure Website" and it will list hosts. Additionally, it has an option to forward to your own server.

(It even has a way to forward to a home server if you setup the Dynamic DNS option under "Configure DNS")